# Can an existing folder be re-declared a virtual environment?

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Not sure if I am asking this the right way but essentially I am looking to "redeclare" or "reinstate" a virtual environment created in VirtualEnvWrapper.

I originally created the virtual environment and I was able to see it when I issued the `workon` command. However, since I was playing around with the file structure (I wanted to move all my Python files into a folder called Python and my Bootstrap files into a folder called Static) the environment no longer appears with the command `workon`

I thought about moving the bin folder etc. back up to the top level would fix it but this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

### Anatomy of virtualenvwrapper

The existing project has two parts:

- the virtualenv, where python and the python libs are installed, and
- the project directory where your code is (that uses the virtualenv).

Virtualenvwrapper adds a third part, the virtualenvwrapper hooks.  These are mainly shell functions that are called at certain times in a project or virtualenvs life cycle.  They live in a third directory - by default, they are installed to ~/.virtualenvs (at least that was true on my Debian system).  The hooks include postactivate, which we will edit below, and a bunch of others such as premkproject, premkvirtualenv, etc.  The following list of keywords gives you the flavour of the hooks:  initialize, pre/post, mk/rm, project/virtualenv, activate/deactivate.
virtualenvwrapper puts these scripts in $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR, which defaults to $WORKON_HOME.

virtualenvwrapper assumes

- all the virtualenvs are in one place ($WORKON_HOME) (defaults to ~/.virtualenvs)
  Let's say you have two virtualenvs, one called MYVENV and the other called MYOTHERVENV
- all the project directories are in another place ($PROJECT_HOME).
  Let's say you have a project "is" in directory /home/me/where/my/proj that uses virtualenv MYVENV.

### how to use workon to work on your pre-existing code and virtualenv

Here I'm assuming all your virtualenvs are in one place (in my case, they are all in /usr/local/virtualenv).

#### one-time operations

*edit ~/.virtualenvs/postactivate to have*

```
    case $env_name in
        MYVENV)
            cd /home/me/where/my/proj/is
            ;;
        MYOTHERVENV)
            cd /home/me/where/my/other/project/is2
            ;;
    esac
```

*links*

```
    for hk in get_env_details initialize postactivate postdeactivate \
            postmkproject postmkvirtualenv postrmproject postrmvirtualenv \
            preactivate predeactivate premkproject premkvirtualenv \
            prermproject prermvirtualenv; do \
        ln -s ~/.virtualenvs/$hk /usr/local/pythonenv/$hk; \
    done
```

#### any time you want to work on your project that uses MYVENV virtualenv

```
    WORKON_HOME=/usr/local/pythonenv workon MYVENV
```

Of course if all your virtualenvs are indeed in the same place, you can define WORKON_HOME in your .profile and you won't have to specify it on the command line every time.